# How to Number Weeks in SQL Query based on Date within Month

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform

I have a BigQuery database with daily sales.  I'd like to aggregate sales by week, but need the weeks to fall within each month meaning, by numbers, I'd have more "weeks" then there is in a year because some weeks will have less than 7 days in a month.

For example, December of 2022 starts on a Thursday and ends on a Saturday.  So, December of this year for what I'm trying to do will have five weeks.  The first week consisting of 3 days (Thurs - Sat) and the other four weeks having 7 days each.

How would I pull that via SQL?

I'm not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

I had a colleague from Russia several years ago who referred to this concept as a "technical period", which he defined as "the week or fraction of week that falls completely within a month."

I have not found this concept supported in any dbms I have worked with, but most dbms will have functions that return year, month, and/or week number (based on calendar weeks).

Therefore, if you include year, month, and week numbers in your query, then you can aggregate on them and achieve the breakdown you are looking for.

In pseudo-sql:

```
select 
    get_year(sales_date) as sales_year, 
    get_month(sales_date) as sales_month, 
    get_week(sales_date) as sales_week,
    sum(sales_amt) as tot_sales_amt
from
    daily_sales
group by
    get_year(sales_date), 
    get_month(sales_date), 
    get_week(sales_date)
```